# expo prebuild with specific cocoapods version

Tags: expo, mobile-development

A recent issue has popped up with the latest cocoapods version in our pipelines. It's related to what is happening here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/26828

So I added a task in the pipelines to pre-install the downgraded cocoapods version, which was successful:

[image]

However when I run expo's prebuild command `npx expo prebuild --platform ios --npm`, it still uses the latest version of cocoapods to try and install:

[image]

Is there any way to get expo's prebuild command to target a specific version in cocoapods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error, I fixed this issue using the following step in my pipeline:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Downgrade cocoapods to version 1.14.3
  inputs:
    targetType: "inline"
    script: |
      pod --version
      # Uninstall all versions of CocoaPods without prompting for confirmation
      gem uninstall cocoapods --all --executables --ignore-dependencies -a -I
      gem install cocoapods -v 1.14.3
```

I used the `pod --version` command to check which version was installed first, then I uninstall all installed versions, using the `--ignore-dependencies` flag so that it completes successfully. then I install v1.14.3. As it's now the only version available, `expo prebuild` uses the correct version and completes successfully.

Comment: See the discussion on github here https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/26828

Comment: confirmed, this works. Thanks so much :)